# error conflicting actions statements

Tags: ansible

My playbook appears as follows:

```
hosts: localhost
tasks:
    name: Get the build synchronize: 
    mode=pull src=jenkins_server_ip:/home/capsilon/Jenkins/trunk/builds/{{item}}/ dest=/home/builds/{{item}} 
    with_items:
        ['as2-client', 'amc-gateway', 'router']

hosts: localhost
tasks:
    name: Zip and send 
    command: /bin/sh "/home/zipfile.sh"

hosts: windows
tasks:
    name: Deployment
    win_get_url: 
        url: 'http://server_ip/builds/build.zip' 
        dest: 'D:\build.zip' 
    win_unzip: 
        src: D:\build.zip 
        dest: D:\
```

Get the following error:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/new_logic_zip.yaml': line 16, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

tasks:
- name: Deployment
^ here
```

What is the error here??
Using latest git developer code. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to have quotes around the *src* and *dest* on the *win_unzip* task which also need to be defined separate to *win_get_url*:

```
  - name: Deployment
    win_get_url:
        url: 'http//server_ip/builds/build.zip'
        dest: 'D:\build.zip'

  - win_unzip:
        src: 'D:\build.zip'
        dest: 'D:\'
```

Comment: correct the indentation of the `win_get_url. There are two spaces to much.

Comment: The solution which worked for me is that i had to call the win_unzip module in a separate task. It cannot be called within the same task (Deployment)